# Jquery flexipage

Tags: jquery, plugins

I thought I would ask this before I dig into a javascript mess. I am working with a pagination plug in called flexipage and it works great...if I use jquery 1.8.2, but I would like to use the latest release of jquery to use some of the other features elsewhere.

I'm just curious if anyone else out there has run into this issue and know what is going on. If not, then I'll dig in a post the answer here for others.

This is the error I'm getting

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .pager .next,
```

edit:
It seems that the actual jquery is throwing the error. Here is a link to the jquery plugin code. https://github.com/vieron/flexipage/blob/master/javascripts/jquery.flexipage.js

Comment: Have you checked a firebug or chrome console to see if there are any errors being flagged in the js file itself?

Comment: yep, the error above is the only thing I get back. I'm guessing it has something to do with a method that they have gotten rid of in the newest version of jquery. My site it live at http://plantationkeyartcorner.com/ if you wanted to look at it

Comment: Please show some relevant code. Is the plugin throwing the error, or your implementation code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this error. Instead of calling the init for the plug in right away. First get the length of the ul and only display the pagination if it hit your length. That should fix the error.

```
if($(".item li").length>3)
 {
   $(".item").flexipage()
 }
```

There seems to be something breaking within the plugin when there are no previous pages to go to so it throws that error. If you eliminate the previous page when there is none, then the error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and found that in the script at line 152, it's written :

```
$(opts.pager_selector+' .next,', opts.wrapper).addClass('disabled');
```

I replaced it by

```
$(opts.pager_selector+' .next', opts.wrapper).addClass('disabled');
```

and now it works. It seems like there was a comma that shouldn't have been there.